# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small - Executing using OCI interface

Tags: php, oracle, types

I am completely flaberghasted and dont understand what i need to do to fix this error. I have a plsql procedure that accepts a varchar2 string and an OUT param which is a number.Can you pls help me as i am learning and new to plsql and php.

type of columns member_name is VARCHAR2(100) and member_id is NUMBER(20)

```
create or replace procedure GET_MEMBER_ID (V_MEMBER_NAME IN  VARCHAR2,V_MEMBER_ID OUT NUMBER ) AS 
BEGIN
SELECT member_id INTO V_MEMBER_ID
FROM mn_member WHERE member_name = V_MEMBER_NAME;
END;
/
```

i execute the above stored procedure from php as follows

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   $conn = oci_connect("$user","$password","$sid");

   $MEMBER_ID=0;
   $MEMBER_NAME='45390';
   echo gettype($MEMBER_NAME), "\n";
   echo gettype($MEMBER_ID), "\n";

   $sql_get_member_id = "BEGIN GET_MEMBER_ID(:MEMBER_NAME,:MEMBER_ID);END;";
   $stmt1 = oci_parse($conn,$sql_get_member_id);

   //  Bind the input parameter
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt1,':MEMBER_NAME',$MEMBER_NAME);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt1,':MEMBER_ID',$MEMBER_ID);

   oci_execute($stmt1);
   echo "Member ID is ".$MEMBER_ID;
?>
```

This is the output i see in php

> string integer 
>   Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at line 1 in rtp2/test.php on line 26
>   Member ID is 0

Comment: Looks like your `member_id` in table is not number. Please post result of `desc mn_member`

Comment: yes you are right,member_id in table is NUMBER(20) and am wondering how do i specify that in the stored procedure as i am getting this error now when i specify V_MEMBER_ID OUT NUMBER(20) Error(1,74): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.

Comment: Specification is OK, you don't need to set up precision in return parameter just type is OK. I suspected it is `varchar2` in table. What is type of `member_name`?

Comment: member_name is VARCHAR2(100)

Comment: No more idea at the moment in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no PHP guy, but from [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php):

"You must specify maxlength when using an OUT bind so that PHP allocates enough memory to hold the returned value."

Maybe try something like:

```
   //  Bind the input parameter
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt1,':MEMBER_NAME',$MEMBER_NAME);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt1,':MEMBER_ID',$MEMBER_ID,20,SQLT_INT);
```

Not sure about the SQLT_INT data type specification necessity.

Comment: God Bless you !