# Call Oracle PL/SQL returning CLOB from Laravel

Tags: php, oracle, laravel

I am using the Laravel-OCI8 package to communicate with Oracle Database from Laravel.
I am calling a function of oracle which returns the result as CLOB.
Here is the Laravel Code:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo_obj->prepare("begin :result := test_pkg.get_data(:param1,:param2,:param3); end;");
$stmt->bindParam(':result', $result, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':param1', $param1, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':param2', $param2, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':param3', $param3, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
return response($result);
```

But I am getting an error : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

I also tried following:

```
$response   = $this->oracle_obj->select("select test_pkg.get_data('$param1','$param2','$param3') as refc from dual");
```

But it's not possible to use the above calling in my case as there are DML operations inside my function.
Is there any other method to call the function of oracle in Laravel using OCI8?

Comment: Does the Oracle function work in other contexts, e.g. from SQL*Plus or SQL Developer? Can you post the code from the function? My hunch is that it is unrelated the context you're using it in, and that the error is in fact in the function itself.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is not cause for **Laravel** or related to use of any other method to call the function of oracle in **Laravel**. It's related to specify the correct explicit data type for the parameter while binding parameters using `$stmt->bindParam` method and setting the length of data type. According to official PHP documentation ..

> To indicate that a parameter is an OUT
>   parameter from a stored procedure, you must explicitly set the length.
>
> Refer to the **data_type** and **length** specification from **PDOStatement::bindParam** PHP doc http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Just an example,

```
$sth->bindParam(':param1', $param1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':param2', $param2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
```

Reference

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php
- https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/337
- [ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small - Executing using OCI interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046218/ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-character-string-buffer-too-small-e?rq=1)

Hope that helps

Comment: "To indicate that a parameter is an OUT parameter from a stored procedure" << The OP isn't using a stored procedure, however - he's returning a value from a function. I don't know whether the same rules apply in this case.

Comment: @DavidFaber A function can have out-parameter, too. nevertheless we don't know  where the error is raised.

Comment: there is no reason to assume that an a parameter is an out parameter.

Comment: The error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small" is basically indicates that, the allocation to hold a particular data type length is not enough.